# nativescript-firebase issue to get push token

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-firebase

I implemented the nativescript-firebase (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) plugin in my mobile app. It used to work fine but since I updated to the 11.1.3 version I cannot get the push token. I tried to get back to the 10.6.3 version but it says it is not available anymore when I execute npm install.

Here is what I do in my `main.js`

```
import { messaging } from "@nativescript/firebase/messaging";
import { firebase } from "@nativescript/firebase"
firebase.init({
    onMessageReceivedCallback: function(message) {
      //do stuff
    }
}).then(function () {
    messaging.getCurrentPushToken().then(token => {
        console.log(token)
    }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  })
},function (error) {
  console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
});
```

This does not log the token but goes into the catch and logs this
`Uncomment firebase-messaging in the plugin's include.gradle first`

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "*****",
  "main": "./src/main.js",
  "version": "4.4.0",
  "description": "A native application built with NativeScript-Vue",
  "author": "*****",
  "license": "Propriétaire",
  "dependencies": {
    "@carployee/openapp": "^1.0.1",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottomnavigationbar": "^6.2.4",
    "@nativescript/appavailability": "^2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/appversion": "^2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/camera": "^5.0.10",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.1.5",
    "@nativescript/datetimepicker": "^2.1.9",
    "@nativescript/firebase": "^11.1.3",
    "@nativescript/imagepicker": "^1.0.6",
    "@nativescript/ios": "^8.1.0",
    "@nativescript/iqkeyboardmanager": "^2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "^3.0.2",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "^2.0.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^4.1.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^3.0.1",
    "@proplugins/nativescript-purchase": "git+https://gitlab.******",
    "@vue/devtools": "^5.3.4",
    "nativescript-dna-deviceinfo": "^3.7.3",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "^3.0.2",
    "nativescript-inappbrowser": "^3.1.2",
    "nativescript-open-app": "^0.3.0",
    "nativescript-phone": "^3.0.2",
    "nativescript-socketio": "^3.3.1",
    "nativescript-toasty": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "^8.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^10.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^10.0.2",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.9.0",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-vue-fonticon": "^1.0.3",
    "nativescript-websockets": "^2.0.0",
    "npm-check": "^5.9.2",
    "npm-check-updates": "^12.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@nativescript/android": "~8.1.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.9.0",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.12.1",
    "sass": "^1.44.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message points you to the plugin's include.gradle file, or more specifically,

```
<app name>/node_modules/@nativescript/firebase/platforms/android/include.gradle
```

where you want to uncomment the line as shown below:

```
// Cloud Messaging (FCM)
 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"
//  implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar"
```

I expect if you reinstall the plugin you can answer the prompts so that this will get set for you.

Comment: Your answer made me realise that I did not have a `include.gradle` file in this location. I tried reinstalling the plugin but it didn't change anything. However, I went to `node_modules/@nativescript/firebase` and ran `npm run config`. There I was prompted for a couple of answers after which I had my `include.gradle` file. So now it works correctly thanks !